# paypal DoDirectPayment method gives error

Tags: php, paypal

I am using `DoDirectPayment` method in my web site. If I am using my `Merchant Username`, `Password` and `signature` then there is no problem and transaction will successful.

But while using my `live Merchant account Username`, `Password` and `signature` then it shows this error

```
10501  - error code

Invalid Configuration 

This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
```

But I am using correct details in `Merchant account`.

Comment: Show us your configuration code ? And check once with your configuration url its sandbox or live paypal url

Answer (score 0):

That error means you do not have DoDirectPayment enabled on the account you're attempting to use it with.

I see this a lot when people sign up with Payments Pro ever since PayPal released the new version of it.

If you've already signed up for Pro and are expecting it to work on your live account, then what probably happened is you got signed up for "PayPal Payments Pro 2.0" which uses the PayFlow API's instead of DoDirectPayment.

DoDirectPayment works with "PayPal Website Payments Pro 3.0" which is actually the older version.

Payments Pro 2.0 is technically supposed to give you full access to both PayFlow and DoDirectPayment, however, I've seen cases where that doesn't work out due to the PayPal account version that you're on.

What it all boils down to is that you need to make sure Payments Pro is active on your live account in the first place, and then figure out exactly which version of Pro it is.